# MsBuild TransformXml Task | How To Target TFS Build Agent only?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have the usual TransformXml task in my csproj file to apply some web.config transforms.

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
  <Target Name="TransformWebConfig">
    <TransformXml Source="$(ProjectDir)\Web.config" Transform="$(ProjectDir)\Web.$(WebConfigReplacement).config" Destination="$(ProjectDir)\Web.config" StackTrace="true" />
  </Target>
```

But - can I put a condition in so this task is only invoked on build on a TFS build agent?

Answer (score 1):

That is easy by adding to your target a condition on a known property, sadly the property varies according to the TFS version and the type of build (XAML vs. vNext).

TFS 2013

`<Target Name="TransformWebConfig" Condition="$(TF_BUILD) != ''">`

vNext

`<Target Name="TransformWebConfig" Condition="$(AGENT_ID) != ''">`

or you can reverse and check if run in VS

`<Target Name="TransformWebConfig" Condition="$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) != 'true'">`

TFS variables are listed [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables) and `BuildingInsideVisualStudio` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171468.aspx#Anchor_6).

Comment: Thanks good information - is there any official documentation regarding TFS known properties!?

Comment: Added links to answer